# Did the concept of Grama devatas exist in earlier Yugas?

Tags: gods, devi, yuga, devatas, kula-devata

Did the concept of Grama-Devis/Devatas ( local/folk deities )exist in the Yugas prior to Kaliyug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brahma vaivarta Purana mentions the existence of Grāma devis.

Prakriti Khanda Chapter 1

[image]

There is also a mention of the Worship of a certain Grāma devi during the wedding of Rukmini.

Krishna janma khanda Chapter 105

[image]

So it certainly seems Grama devatas existed in earlier times as well.